# Ajax contact form endpoint in wordpress - internal server error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

I've inherited a half finished project from another developer and with my very little knowledge of ajax and PHP I've found myself stuck on this contact form.

Ajax is successfully sending the fields to the endpoint but according to chromes dev tools it's throwing a 500 internal server error and also not sending the email.

If I am missing something here I would really appreciate the help.

This is the code I have in the endpoint:

```
<?php
/****************************
* ENQUIRY FORM - Controller *
*****************************

 AJAX END-Point, outputs JSON.

 Processes user's form inputs, and sends email to site admins.

*/


header('Content-type: application/json');

$form_values = $_POST['enquiry'];

// returned JSON object:
$output = array();
$output['message'] = "form submission received";
$output['enquiry'] = $form_values;

// set values for 'to', 'from' and 'subject'
$send_to = get_option("admin_email");
$subject = "Artbank WebForm Submission";

//change name of "sender" 
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'artbank_wp_mail_from_name' );
function artbank_wp_mail_from_name( $email_from ) {
    return 'Contact Form';
}

$message = "The following submission was received:\n\n"
$message .= "Name: ".$form_values['name'];
$message .= "\nEmail: ".$form_values['email'];
$message .= "\nPhone: ".$form_values['phone'];
$message .= "\nInfo: ".$form_values['info'];
$message .= "\nWishlist Items: ".$form_values['wishlist-items'];


wp_mail($send_to, $subject, $message);  

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

Comment: *"internal server error"* - Means, check your logs. Plus, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` which you are most likely not using; the error is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You forget the semicolon:

```
$message = "The following submission was received:\n\n";
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've added the missing semicolon in there but still receiving the error.

Comment: It's strange, did you try to comment some piece of code to debug?